# why does lambda think there is no argument? python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, lambda

I have made a keypad as part of my app

```
AmountEntered = ""
def addvalue(AmountEntered, value):
   AmountEntered = AmountEntered + value
def Clear(AmountEntered):
   AmountEntered = ""
Number = tk.Button(root, text = "7", command = lambda AmountEntered: addvalue(AmountEntered, "7"))
Number.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')
```

(Number is repeated for all numbers 0-9)

Whenever I click on any of the buttons I get the error message:
TypeError: () missing 1 required positional argument: 'AmountEntered'

What is this actually referring to and how do I fix it?

Comment: In the lambda, use another name instead of AmountEntered, just x or a, it's local, it would help comprehension

Comment: For that matter, all variables should be in lower case: `amount_entered`, `clear`, `number`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `tk.Button` doesn't expect its command to take an argument, and doesn't pass one. It's your callback that is expecting an argument and not receiving one.

Whatever you are expecting your callback to receive has to come from somewhere other else. In this case, it appears `addvalue` can simply treat `AmountEntered` as a global variable (though there are likely better alterntives):

```
amount_entered = ""

def add_value(value):
   global amount_entered
   amount_entered += value

def clear():
   global amount_entered
   amount_entered = ""

number = tk.Button(root, text="7", command=lambda: addvalue("7"))
number.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='nesw')
```

Answer (score 1):

The error stems from Tk trying to call your command (lambda) function with zero parameters (as a button's command has no parameter).

You've declared that it does require a parameter though, hence the error.

```
Number = tk.Button(root, text = "7", command = lambda: addvalue(AmountEntered, "7"))
```

should work (but likely won't really do what you'd like it to, but that's another bug).

Comment: This takes the error away but now the button does nothing.